# Advance localnet epoch for testing

Tags: epoch, localnet

If we have some program that uses `let epoch_now = Clock::get()?.epoch;` and we want to write typescript tests around what happens when the epoch advances, is there a way to advance the localnet time or make epochs on localnet very short (e.g., several seconds)?

For time, it's easy to compile with a localnet flag that turns any time-equivalent into something small like a few seconds. For epochs, they are unfortunately always two days.

Obviously waiting 2 days is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Bankrun](https://github.com/kevinheavey/solana-bankrun.git). I haven't used it but it aims to be a wrapper around `solana-program-test` which means it likely has what you want.

The clock-related functions shown [here](https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/mango-v4/blob/511814ca979ad848be1326f36d6b2f363941d54f/programs/mango-v4/tests/program_test/solana.rs#L77) are examples of the useful functionality `solana-program-test` provides that should help in your case. With it, you can modify the clock sysvar information at will. Bankrun should in theory offer a way to do the same in Typescript.